# How to load a very large into Tensorflow and create minibatchs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a hdf5 file that has been written into the disk by a python code (I only have the file, not the code). The size of this file is 90GB and the data in this file has the following format: (N, 250,360,3). Just as side note, the data can't fit into memory.

Now I want to write a data loader in Tensorflow where each time just loads M samples from this file (M is way smaller than N).

What would be the best way to do this? Any pointer to a code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tensorflow MNIST tutorial shows how this can be done:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

If you look at the implementation on Github, you'll see that it uses a `next_batch` function to read batches of inputs 100 at a time.

The implementation of `next_batch` lives here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160

You would need to implement something similar for your data set. I'm not particularly familiar with HDF5, but you can use any Python library to do the loading; it doesn't have to be specific to Tensorflow.

Hope that helps!